# Elaboration on weight change for output layer in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I have trouble understanding the section regarding backpropagation in Murphy's Machine Learning book.

He derives the weight change for the output layer (16.68) as follows:

$\nabla_{\mathbf{w}_k} J_n = \frac{\partial J_n}{\partial b_{nk}} \nabla_{\mathbf{w}_k} b_{nk} = \frac{\partial J_n}{\partial b_{nk}} \mathbf{z}_n$

$b_{nk} = \sum_j w_{kj} g(a_{nj})$ (16.73)

$b_{nk}$ normally is given as the sum of all weighted outputs from the prior layer.
Here, however it is given as follows:

$b_{nk} = \mathbf{w}_k^T \mathbf{z}_n$

I don't quite understand where that $\mathbf{z}_n$ comes from and how it fits in there. What am I missing?